# PHP checkdate variants

Tags: php, validation, date

I found a php function [checkdate()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php) , but strangely enough it only seems to accept data in format of `int $month , int $day , int $year`. However I am passing the date as a string (example `"2012-06-13"`) so I came up with this workaround, because **I would only allow date entered in such format**. Unfortunately I am feeling this is both insecure and not a nice approach to the problem:

```
function CheckAdditional($value)
{
    $data = explode("-", $value);

    return checkdate($data[1], $data[2], $data[0]);
}
```

Question: is there a better way to check whether the date is valid?

Comment: I don't see any problems with your method. Clean and simple.

Comment: There's 'valid', and then there's 'correct' - which one are you aiming for? `01/02/03` is valid, but depending on how you read it, it can be very very incorrect.

Comment: What is the insecure part do you think?

Comment: @MarcB - I want the data be both valid and correct. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: I think he meant getting data from client side, he might have js validation but still on server side you may want some protection.

Comment: @xdazz - I am not really sure, I'm afraid :/ Jon said it is clean and simple and that's what I think too, but maybe it is too simple and we're not seeing something lurking and thus deeper data checking is needed?

Comment: @AndriusNaruševičius: This problem is intrinsically ambiguous, you can only be 100% sure if ***a)*** the day is > 12 (and the year is a 4 digit number, or a two digit number > 31, or ***b)*** you ask your users to stick to a convention (personally, I like `YYYY-mm-dd`) and use that order with `checkdate()`.

Comment: What about this? http://codepad.org/Nstz0mBG

Comment: @AndriusNaruševičius I don't see anything dangerous here. At worst, the date will be rejected because of bad formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

function CheckAdditional($value)
{
    return date('Y-m-d', strtotime($value)) == $value;
}

?>
```

After several tests from both me and the people who tried to help me with my answer, I came up with this which suits me perfectly fine and is both easy and really reliable solution in my opinion as none was able to prove it wrong so far.

Comment: By itself, that is wrong (1 digit input suffices). Plus, it's way worse than `checkdate()`.

Comment: What you mean by `1 digit input suffices`?

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
function checkDateFormat($date){  
//match the format of the date  
if (preg_match ("/^([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})$/", $date, $parts))  {    
    //check weather the date is valid of not        

    if(checkdate($parts[2],$parts[3],$parts[1]))          
       return true;        
    else         
       return false;  
    }  
else    
return false;}
```

Credits: http://roshanbh.com.np/2008/05/date-format-validation-php.html

Comment: Surprisingly, this turned out to be the best answer of all so far.

Answer (score 1):

Just in order to be safe you can do

```
date("Y-m-d", strtotime($yourdatestr));
```

In that way even if the format may be wrong it will in most cases correct it.

Comment: Bare in mind that `strtotime()` can return false. It can also adjust the date, for instance `2012-02-31` should come out as `2012-03-02` (I think).

Comment: 2012-02-31 is an invalid date! therefore it does returns the possible valid date.

Comment: `date('Y-m-d', strtotime('test'));` - hmm, this actually seem as a very interesting option. Since this function always returns a date, I can then compare the strings and now it seems like a good stuff!

Comment: @Nasaralla: Indeed, the date is invalid, but this approach makes it valid. Depending on what the OP wants this may not be a very good idea.

Comment: yes I understand then there is no point doing check date... hmmm

Comment: @AndriusNaruševičius: Oh, that will just fail and return `false == 0`, meaning you'll end up with the timestamp for the Unix epoch (`1970-01-01`).

Comment: @Nasaralla: There is! With `checkdate()` you would know the date is invalid and you could ask the user to try and fix it.

Comment: @AndriusNaruševičius: That won't work either, but now I must go see Portugal kick Denmark ass! :P

Comment: Can you think of a value that would return `true` while the data is incorrect or invalid? :)

Comment: @AndriusNaruševičius: Yes, http://codepad.org/yA1Rfg9v and many more. Also, like I stated in my comment to your question, this is still ambiguous (is `03` the day or the month?).

Comment: @AndriusNaruševičius: I suggest you look into http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.intldateformatter.php.

Comment: @AlixAxel it comes pretty clear when you try to write `2012-03-15` and the data is still valid. Thus the program interprets the input correctly. Not to mention it will be clearly said how to input the data. Moreover, first two and the last two inputs of data will not only fail due to the rules set but also to length rules of the field which will be equal to 10 and 10 only. Thus I defended my method so far :P

Comment: @AndriusNaruševičius: Then we have to disagree. What you're saying doesn't make much sense to me, if you only allow the input dates in one format, you don't need to rely on the fuzzyness of `strtotime()` and `checkdate()` will be the best possible tool for the job. Now that I read your question more carefully I understand that you only want to allow dates in one format (I understood differently the first time) - `checkdate()` ***is*** the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

```
$jahr = (int) $_POST['jahr'];
$monat =  (int) $_POST['monat'];
$tag = (int) $_POST['tag'];
$datum = "$tag. $monat. $jahr";

if (checkdate($monat, $tag, $jahr) == FALSE) {
    $allesok = false;
    $fehlermeldung .= "<p class='fehler'>Ungültiges Datum $datum!</p>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you limit the user inputs to be valid only in one format (what about localization?), then you just can parse the input by yourself, using a regexp-function or splitting the input by "-" and check whether it turns into an array with three digit values…

Answer (score 0):

```
function DDC($dates){ // Date Day Control
    $dy = substr($dates,0,4);
    $dm = substr($dates,5,2);
    $dd = substr($dates,8,2);
    for($i=0; $i<3; $i++){
        if(!checkdate($dm,$dd,$dy)){
            $dd--;
        }else{$i=3;}
    }
    return $dy.'.'.$dm.'.'.$dd;
}
echo DDC('2013.02.31');
//2013.02.28
```