# How to create a date from mm and yy php?

Tags: php

I have two variables:

```
$mm = "01";
$yy = "12";
```

I need to create a date and compare with current `date()` to check if date is expired.

Comment: I have tried to use `strtime("%m", $mm)`

Comment: No day? What should the expected date from those variables be? First day of that month? Last day?

Comment: Day must be the first day

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP checkdate variants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11018768/php-checkdate-variants)

Answer (score 2):

```
$mm = "01";
$yy = "12";

if (DateTime::createFromFormat('y-m', $yy . '-' . $mm) > new DateTime()) {
    //code here
} else {
     //code here
}
```

Comment: What is `$mm` is `39` and year is `01`?

Comment: when u may use `checkdate()` function to validate parameters

Comment: @Famida You could just try it out. 39 and 01 would produce `2004-03-01`